# Fast Keyevent Simulation (Android Shell)

Tags: android, adb, sh

Using `adb shell input text <String>` or `adb shell input keyevent <KEYCODE_NAME>` works perfectly fine in sending text to the android device, but my issue is speed.

Using something like `input keyevent KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_SPACE KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_ENTER;` will type the text quickly, but separating it into 2 commands will result in a (1 sec) delay between the 2 commands (Much Slower).

Sample Shell Code:

Method 1 (Much faster):

```
input keyevent KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_ENTER KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_ENTER;
```

Method 2:

```
input keyevent KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_ENTER;
input keyevent KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_ENTER;
```

I would like to type a large text as fast as possible, but having a shell script with `input keyevent` followed by a large combination of KEYCODE_A for instance, will not be executed. (Large Shell Commands are aborted)

What would be the best way to send large text without having long delays?
Would `sendevent` be faster in sending large text?

**Note:**

- The weakness of `input text <String>` is that it also has a limit to it's size and it can't perform special keyevents inside of it (Like the Back Button or Enter/New Line ).

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `input keyevent $(for i in $(seq 500); do echo 29; done; echo 30)` worked just fine on my device. do you need to inject more than 500 keycodes at once?

Comment: @AlexP. Your method works fine, but the issue is that there will be a 1 sec delay between every command which is the issue i was trying to avoid.

Comment: I was not suggesting a solution but rather questioning your use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realise you are after Android Shell, but I think you have exhausted the options available to you there.

I know of one way that is faster than what you have tried, using `Instrumentation`:

```
final Instrumentation mInst = new Instrumentation();

mInst.sendKeySync(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keycode));
mInst.sendKeySync(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keycode));
```

Comment: What is Instrumentation? How and where to implement this?